# Calculate binary real number

Tags: floating-point, binary

I have something to ask about fractional numbers

I am trying to calculate binary number. For example, `101.01`.

```
2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0 (dot/point) 2^-1 2^-2 2^-3
```

[This is Photo, if not clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYyK.png)

Like in the picture if on the left (point), the exponent is positive
if to the right (point), the exponent is negative.

To calculate the number that is to the left of the dot, is required.

```
101 = 2^0 + 2^2 = 5
```

And to calculate the numbers to the right of the dot.

```
01 = 2^-2 = 0.25
```

My question is why a negative doesn't have an exponent of 0 (2^0),

whereas a positive has an exponent of 0.

Isn't 0 a neutral number, neither positive nor negative?

Comment: "why a negative doesn't have an exponent of 0 (2^0)" --> Why do you think a negative should have a value of 0 (2^0)?  Note: 2^0 as in `pow(2,0)` is 1.0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica because I thought, if the positive exponent has 2^0, then the negative should be the same

Comment: Kangkue, when you have "a negative", are you talking about a negative number (x < 0)? A value less than 1.0 or what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica like in the picture
```2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0 (dot/point) 2^-1 2^-2 2^-3```

positive exponents start with 2^0,

while the direct negative exponent is 2^-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is, *Because the `.` or radix point does **not** quite line up with the "neutral" point.*

The longer answer starts out with a review of what you may already know:

The real number line is symmetric around 0 for addition.  0 is the "neutral point", neither positive nor negative.  (Mathematicians say that 0 is the "additive identity".)

The positive numbers are symmetric around 1 for multiplication.  1 is the "neutral point".  (Mathematicians say that 1 is the "multiplicative identity".)

And the two systems line up very, very nicely when it comes to powers.  That's what the [image you linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYyK.png) is trying to show.  I usually think of a table like this:

| N |  | 10<sup>N</sup> |  |  | 2<sup>N</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10<sup>3</sup> | 1000 |  | 2<sup>3</sup> | 8 |
| 2 | 10<sup>2</sup> | 100 |  | 2<sup>2</sup> | 4 |
| 1 | 10<sup>1</sup> | 10 |  | 2<sup>1</sup> | 2 |
| 0 | 10<sup>0</sup> | 1 |  | 2<sup>0</sup> | 1 |
| -1 | 10<sup>-1</sup> | 0.1 |  | 2<sup>-1</sup> | ½ |
| -2 | 10<sup>-2</sup> | 0.01 |  | 2<sup>-2</sup> | ¼ |
| -3 | 10<sup>-3</sup> | 0.001 |  | 2<sup>-3</sup> | ⅛ |

The middle row of this table — the N = 0 row — is the center or pivot point or "neutral" row, the row that everything is symmetric around, with N = 0 and X<sup>N</sup> = 1.  (I'd color this row differently if I knew how to in Stack Overflow markdown.)

I'm not enough of a mathematician to say if it just inherently *has* to be this way.  I remember, when I first learned this stuff, that it wasn't obvious what X<sup>0</sup> should mean, or X raised to the power of a negative number.  But when you draw that table, and watch the patterns, you can see that X<sup>0</sup> has to be 1, because as you move down the columns, you're repeatedly dividing by 10 or 2 (just as when you're moving to the right in the image you linked).

The other thing to notice is that X<sup>-N</sup> is always equal to 1/X<sup>N</sup>.  That ends up showing what X raised to a negative power should mean, and it's another way of seeing that multiplication is symmetric around 1, and lines up with addition being symmetric around 0.

But, returning to your question, you're right: When you use a positional notation system to write a fraction like

```
101.01
```

the `.` character is not exactly at the "neutral point".  The `.` has the neutral point squarely to its left, and everything to the right of the `.` is negative.  I don't know of a satisfying way to explain this discrepancy.

You can imagine alternate notations with the "neutral point" marked in a more symmetric way, like 10{1}01, or with a dot or bar under the middle 1, but I've never heard of such a thing.
(It might be reminiscent of the way that vowels are indicated using dots above the consonants in Arabic languages.
There was also the "[bar notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm#Negative_logarithms)" used in [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms) of
[common logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm), although that's a different beast, too.)

---

Addendum: In the comments you asked about several more examples, although I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  I would render those examples using the nonce {} notation, and convert them back to decimal, like this:

```
                         2³  2²  2¹  2⁰  2⁻¹ 2⁻² 2⁻³
                         8   4   2   1   ½   ¼   ⅛

                                 0   0   0   1
   0b0.01  →   0{0}01  =         0 + 0 + 0 + ¼     =   ¼ =  0.25

                         1   1   0   1   1   0   1
0b1101.101 → 110{1}101 = 8 + 4 + 0 + 1 + ½ + 0 + ⅛ = 13⅝ = 13.625

                             1   0   1   0   1
 0b101.01  →  10{1}01  =     4 + 0 + 1 + 0 + ¼     =  5¼ =  5.25

                         8   4   2   1   ½   ¼   ⅛
```

To me this is all very regular and consistent.  I've lined things up so that 2⁰ = 1 runs right down the middle, and that's always the place that would be enclosed by `{}` in the nonce notation.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you for answering my question.
Previously there is something I want to ask,

there is something I want to ask,
If
example,
`0.25`,
which mean,
`0.01`,
is our view like this,
`0{0}1`, or `{0}01`.

Comment: and whether the median line, affected by how much value,
example,
  `13.625 = 110{1}.101`
totals `7` . (`1` because it is in the middle).

Comment: Or influenced by which number is an integer,
example,
` 5.25 = 101.01` because `101` is an integer, `10{1}` becomes the center line, (since any number raised to the power of `0` becomes `1`).

Comment: and for example if it is affected by which number is an integer,
example,
`0.25 = 0.01` which means `{0}.01 = 1 (because 2^0) .25`. inconsistent

Comment: @Kangkue Yes, 0.25 would be `{0}01` (or perhaps for clarity `0{0}01`) in the more "balanced" notation.  There is no 7 in `110{1}101`, because to get 7 you'd need `11{1}`.  I don't know what you mean by "affected by which number is an integer", and I don't see any inconsistency in ¼ = 0.25 = `0b0.01` → `0{0}01`.  See the addendum to the answer I just posted.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for explaining carefully this really helped me, and sorry for disturbing your free time, to answer my question

Comment: Sorry my previous question confused you, I'll explain

`.` dot, as a separator between integers and fractions
as an example
`5.25 = 101.01` ( `.` Separator between whole and fraction)

which mean
`
2³ 2² 2⁰ 2⁻¹ 2⁻²
1 0 1 . 0 1
`
My question is, why is `2⁰` included in an integer?
is it because if we add them up the result will be `1`

Comment: @Kangkue We define fractions as "anything less than 1".  Not "less than or equal to 1", but strictly "less than 1".  2⁰ is 1, and 1 is not less than 1, so 1 is not a fraction, it is a whole number.  It's as fundamental as that, I think.

Comment: KTT Thank you, sir, for fulfilling the questions I asked, and sorry if there are many sentences that are difficult to understand

Answer (score 1):

This works the same way in decimal (regular numbers)

you can have 5, for example, which = `5*10^0`, or for completeness we can say 05.0 = `0*10^1 + 5*10^0 + 0*10^0`. None of these numbers are negative. The *exponents* are negative.

The confusion is that the number itself, `05.0` is not negative, while some of the exponents are. We could also have written it as `05.0=0*10 + 5*1 + 0*1/10`

Taking this back to your example, we can thus clear up the confusion by writing the entirety of `101.01` as a single summation. It is as follows:

`1*(2*2) + 0*(2) + 1*(2/2) + 0*(1/(2)) + 1*(1/(2*2)) = 1*4 + 1*1 + 1/4 = 5.25`